# What are Dependencies in Angular?

Tags: angular, npm, npm-install

I am new to Angular,I have heard about dependencies many times while learning Angular. Today I searched it on Google but I was unable to find any definition of Dependencies in Angular.So,Can anyone explain me what dependencies are in angular and how dependency updates causes problem in Angular Application.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A dependency can be user (your) code, or 3rd party.

User Code Dependency: When Component A uses functions that live on Component B thus you need to provide or use the injector tree to get to it. In this case Component A will not work without Component B because of a user code dependency.

3rd Party: When your Component A needs some code you don't want to write. For example some of the cool operators found in RxJs. You would usually get this dependency installed through NPM. However if the dependency is not installed or you get a mismatched version that is not compatible with what Component A needs to function you would have a problem.

Hope this helps, let me know.